# What size are the correct fittings for 1 1/4" ABS pipe?

Tags: pipe, fitting, abs

I need to plumb into an existing ABS drain, labelled as "ABS/DWV 1 1/4" schedule 40 ", but for the life of me cant find any 1 1/4" fittings!!!

[image: Photograph of pipe showing labelling]

My suspicion is that the pipe is 1 1/4" ID, and I need to buy 1 1/2" OD fittings.

Before I trundle down to Home Depot, is anyone able to confirm my suspicion (or do I have the most useless, redundant piping ever?

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to trundle down to a plumbing supply place; it's probably an uncommon size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They definitely exist (in Canada at least).

Sample "big box" listing for "abs 1 1/4" :

https://www.rona.ca/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/RonaAjaxCatalogSearchView?catalogId=10051&searchKey=RonaEN&urlLangId=-1&content=&langId=-1&keywords=abs+1%22+1%2F4&storeId=10151

Comment: I am sure that ABS DWV Schedule 40 is legal to use where I live, but it does not in fact appear to be used here in new construction. Every new installation I see now in the City of Dallas is PVC schedule 40. The drains in our 47-year-old Fox and Jacobs tract house in Dallas are plumbed in ABS, but I am not aware of any other ABS installations here.

Comment: Levi, where is this installation of ABS drains?

Comment: Thanks Jeff - I looked at HD & Lowes, but did not actually check Rona!

Comment: Jim - This install is in Ontario.